# Why does temperature disappear from At A Glance and the lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens, home-screen, weather

It disappeared out of the blue a few weeks ago. I searched the web and did a trick to make it reappear. It was shown for weeks and then suddenly disappeared again a few days ago.

What causes this, a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*While reporting bugs like this, mentioning your Device Model and Android build would be beneficial for the community to help answer the question properly*

I've also faced this.

This is a known issue in Google App's Beta versions.

Temporary solution : add one more At a Glance Widget and if you see weather on existing widget , remove the newly added widget.

Permanent workaround:

1. Remove the At a Glance widget .
2. Unroll from beta and wait a few minutes patiently.
3. Clear data and cache of Google app and add the widget back .

( Incase the widget is not removable for your device, just try step 2 and 3 )

Comment: I'm not using a beta version of Android.

Comment: @DamnVegetables im speaking about the beta version of Google App... Go to playstore and verify whether you're running *Google App (beta)*